# Синтаксическая роль части предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, в предложении: "А после дождя в воздухе остаётся множество мелких капелек, каждая словно крошечная линза, и лучи разного цвета по-разному проходят через них" выражение "каждая словно крошечная линза" является сравнительным оборотом или придаточной частью (тогда "каждая" будет выполнять роль подлежащего, а "линза" - части СИС)? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, я проконсультировался **с Граммой.ру** ( там отвечают научные сотрудники).

**Вот ответ.**

Что касается предложения ***А после дождя в воздухе остаётся множество мелких капелек, каждая словно крошечная линза , и лучи разного цвета по-разному проходят через них*,** то сочетание ***каждая словно крошечная линза*** невозможно квалифицировать однозначно. Оно может быть 1) предикативной частью сложного бессоюзного предложения, где каждая — подлежащее, а словно крошечная линза — составное именное сказуемое или 2) сравнительный оборот. Первая трактовка кажется точнее.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос неоднократно обсуждался в Сети, интерес же вызвала часть предложения с **неопределенной синтаксической ролью**, например:

09.06.2021 Это CCП или cлoжнoe c paзными видaми cвязи? Ecли кoнкpeтнeй, вызывaeт coмнeниe следующая  чacть: *кaждaя, cлoвнo мaлeнькaя кaпля.* **Mнeния paзoшлиcь.** Heкoтopыe лингвиcты yтвepждaют, чтo этo пpидaтoчнaя чacть. Ho тoгдa oт кaкoй чacти oнa зaвиcит? Иcтoчник: https://www.textologia.ru/faq/?q=490

Дано предложение: *(1) А после дождя в воздухе остаётся множество мелких капелек, (2) **каждая словно крошечная линза** , (3) и лучи разного цвета по-разному проходят через них.*

1. Не могу согласиться с решением Граммы.ру. Прежде всего, это касается  **интонации**. Предложение делится на три части, и явно чувствуется **вставочная** интонация второго предложения, в то время как  союз И связывает первое и третье.
2. Это возможно, если второе предложение считать **придаточным определительным** с пропущенным союзным словом:

*(1) А после дождя в воздухе остаётся множество мелких капелек, (2) каждая (**из которых**) словно крошечная линза, (3) и лучи разного цвета по-разному проходят через них.*

3. Другой вариант — считать вторую часть  **присоединительной** конструкцией, обособленной запятыми.
4. Сравнительный оборот не подходит однозначно по конструкции, но и  **вариант с БСП не подходит тоже.**

Здесь **нет перечисления,** значит, предложения (1) и (2) неоднородные. А какие между ними отношения, распространительно-присоединительнве?  Но тогда бы это выглядело так: «*А после дождя в воздухе остаётся множество мелких капелек,  каждая из них словно крошечная линза*». Причем это закрытый ряд, только два предложения.

Таким образом, это никак не БСП.

**А что это, как вы думаете?**